# How to pass errors from effects to actions in NGRX

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I am new to NGRX and I'm trying to pass an error that's thrown in an effect to an action to put the error object into the store.
This seems to be working on my localhost but when deployed on the server I get this error :

`Error: Detected unserializable action at "error". https://ngrx.io/guide/store/configuration/runtime-checks#strictactionserializability`

My action looks like this :

```
export const loginFailed = createAction(
  "[Login dialog] User log in failed",
  props<{error : any}>()
);
```

The catch statement in my effect :

```
catchError((error) => of(AuthActions.loginFailed({error : error})))
```

So, some questions :

- Why do I only see this error on the server and not on my localhost?
- Why is error being an "any" type, not serializable?
- Is there a better way to pass errors to my store?

I've tried putting the "Error" interface as the type of the error in the action props, but this gives me the identical error.

In the docs of ngrx I didn't find any article about error objects or how to manage them.

Answer (score 0):

An `Error` instance is a class instance, which is unserializable.
It should have the same behavior on all environments, unless there's something in your NgRx configuration that disables or enables this behavior.

For more info see the docs: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/configuration/runtime-checks#strictactionserializability